# Powershell: FileSystemWatcher monitor only certain subfolders

Tags: powershell, wildcard, filesystemwatcher

How can I monitor only certain subfolders of a folder with a FileSystemWatcher in Powershell?

I create a new FileSystemWatcher like so:

```
$folder = 'path\to\root\monitoring\folder'
$filter = '*.xml'   

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher

$fsw.Path = $folder
$fsw.Filter = $filter
$fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
```

In that root monitoring folder there is a tree-like structure:

task01

- working
- approval
- approved

task02

- working
- approval
- approved

task03

- working
- approval
- approved

I only want to check changes in the "approved" Folders.

The easiest solution would be

```
$folder = 'path\to\root\monitoring\folder\*\approved'
```

but that doesn't quite seem to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to set up a watcher on each directory that you want to monitor as there is no wildcard support for paths (see the **Exceptions Section** on this link: [FileSystemWatcher.Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.path(v=vs.110).aspx))
Trying to work the Filter property to support a possible wildcard path will not work either.

Comment: That's bad, as the "approved"-folders are a variable number of folders with different names. Seems like I have to monitor every change and then filter the ones I'm interested in afterwards. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Well, a possible workaround would be to evaluate the "Path" value in our Event Handlers (Created, Changed, etc.) to see if it fits the pattern for the Folder(s) that you want to monitor and handle. It if fits, then continue to run the code in the Event Handler, if not, then simply return out of the Handler.

Answer (score 0):

Next code might do what you need, with appropriate modifications:

```
$action = {
  $fullpath = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
  $currfolder = Split-Path $fullpath -Parent
  $filename = Split-Path $fullpath -Leaf
  # Create a text file only if changes happened in folder 'approved'
  # If $currfolder contains 'approved', e.g. create ACK_...txt file, otherwise skip watching over other folders:
  if ($folder.Contains('approved'))
  {
     New-Item -ItemType File -Path "$currfolder\ACK_$filename.txt"
  }
}
```